# Laravel middleware terminate not called when using constructor version

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel version: 5.1.46

routes.php

`Route::get('/rocha', 'RochaController@index');`

Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'Age' => \App\Http\Middleware\AgeMiddleware::class,
        'Role' => \App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

RochaController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class RochaController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('Role');
    }
    public function index() {
        echo '<br>Hi I am index';
    }
}
```

RochaMiddleware.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class RoleMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        echo '<br>Hi I am middleware';
        return $next($request);
    }


    public function terminate($request, $response) {
        echo '<br>Shtting down...';
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Hi I am middleware
Hi I am index
```

When I use middleware inside the controller via its constructor `$this->middleware('Role')` the `terminate()` function does not get called. When I switch the code taking out the constructor in the controller and change the route to the following the `terminate()` function gets called:

```
Route::get('/rocha', [
    'middleware' => 'Role',
    'uses' => 'RochaController@index'
]);
```

Result:

```
Hi I am middleware
Hi I am index
Shtting down...
```

Why does the constructor version (`$this->middleware('Role')`) prevent the `terminate()` function from being called?

Why does the route version work and the `terminate()` function is called as opposed to the above?

Answer (score 7):

> If you define a terminate method on your middleware, it will automatically be called after the response is ready to be sent to the browser.

from [terminable-middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#terminable-middleware)

I think you misunderstand the usage of `terminate` method. Laravel actually call the `terminate` method, but the browser will not show the output of `terminate`. Because the response has been sent to browsers.

You can use this `terminate` method to test whether the call is successful.

```
public function terminate($request, $response)
{
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/1.txt', 'hello terminate');
}
```

By the way, I'm test your code, it always output:

```
Hi I am middleware
Hi I am index
```

I also wonder why you can get `Shtting down...`

Comment: Ok. Thank you.

Comment: instead of creating file, try `app('log')->info('Middleware::terminate');`.